# Android Studio keep getting "Error:(60, 12) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype"

Tags: java, android

I keep getting this error "Error:(60, 12) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype" on my last 2 @Overrides im not sure where i went wrong, any help would be helpful. I added the Button billspliting and everything then when to poop. I try to build the APK but I keep getting the two over ride errors.

```
private TextView totaltextview;
private EditText PercentageTxt;
private EditText Numbertxt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    totaltextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Totaltextview);
    PercentageTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PercentageTxt);
    Numbertxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Numbertxt);


    Button CalcBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CalcBtn);
    CalcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            float percentage = Float.parseFloat(PercentageTxt.getText().toString());
            float dec = percentage / 100;
            float total = dec * Float.parseFloat(Numbertxt.getText().toString()) + Float.parseFloat(Numbertxt.getText().toString());
            totaltextview.setText(Float.toString(total));

            Button billspliting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button123);
            billspliting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Myotheractivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            });


        }


       @Override
        public boolean OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean OnOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        ;
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take `OnCreateOptionsMenu` and `OnOptionsItemSelected` outside of `CalcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()` as these method are present in Activity not in `OnClickListener`.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    totaltextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Totaltextview);
    PercentageTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PercentageTxt);
    Numbertxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Numbertxt);


    Button CalcBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CalcBtn);
    CalcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            float percentage = Float.parseFloat(PercentageTxt.getText().toString());
            float dec = percentage / 100;
            float total = dec * Float.parseFloat(Numbertxt.getText().toString()) + Float.parseFloat(Numbertxt.getText().toString());
            totaltextview.setText(Float.toString(total));

            Button billspliting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button123);
            billspliting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Myotheractivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }            
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Umm do you think you could give me an example of what that would look like?

Comment: I still keep getting the whole Error:(66, 13) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype even when moving it outside

Comment: @MatthewGillen In Java, method names start with lowercase characters. E.g. `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.